# Assigning remaining container space to a single flex item

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Let's say I have a flex container which contains children that fully occupy the space of the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

On click, I would like to add extra space to the item number 2, without shrinking the other blocks. The idea is to add the additional space to the width of the container, and ideally to distribute this space only to the clicked item. However, I am not sure if it is possible via flexbox to assign additional space to only a single flex item.

P.S I need my items to resize, therefore the items need to have the flex-grow set to 1.

Comment: There is no "extra" space available if  the others aren't going to change size. it's not really clear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the post a little bit, hope my intention is a bit clearer now :)

Answer (score 1):

if you allow them to grow and to shrink, you probably do not want to set a flex-basis value and leave it to auto.

Any of the child can be resized via width or min-width or flex-grow.

here an example with those 3 rules and flex-basis set to auto.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.container {
  display: flex; 
  width: 150px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;  
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}

.item:focus { 
  border-color:red
}

.width .item:focus {
  width: 66.66%; 
}

.min-width .item:focus {
  min-width: 66.66%;
  border-color:yellow
}


.grow-4 .item:focus {
  flex-grow:4;/* 4 , the 2 other elements use 2 . 4/6=66% */
  border-color:hotpink
}
```

```html
<div class="container width">
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div><div class="container min-width">
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div><div class="container grow-4">
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To avoid shrinking : Do not set the flex-shrink value to 1 but 0 and allow wrapping or overflow ?
flex-basis can do the job on its own and flex-grow can even be reset to 0 .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}

.container {
  display: flex; 
  width: 150px;
  background:silver
  
}
.container + .container {flex-wrap:wrap;}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;  
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}

.item:focus { 
  border-color:red;
  flex-basis: 66.66%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" tabindex="0">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```